# How to parse XML in R with different number of subnodes and multiple nodes with the same name

Tags: r, xml

I have the following XML file that I would like to parse in R.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><CONSOLIDATED_LIST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://www.un.org/sc/resources/sc-sanctions.xsd" dateGenerated="2016-12-21T19:09:23.456-05:00">
        <INDIVIDUALS>
            <INDIVIDUAL>
                <DATAID>6908434</DATAID>
                <VERSIONNUM>1</VERSIONNUM>
                <FIRST_NAME>ABD</FIRST_NAME>
                <SECOND_NAME>AL-KHALIQ</SECOND_NAME>
                <THIRD_NAME> AL-HOUTHI </THIRD_NAME>
                <UN_LIST_TYPE>Yemen</UN_LIST_TYPE>
                <REFERENCE_NUMBER>YEi.001</REFERENCE_NUMBER>
                <LISTED_ON>2014-11-07</LISTED_ON>
                <NAME_ORIGINAL_SCRIPT>عبدالخالق الحوثي</NAME_ORIGINAL_SCRIPT>
                <COMMENTS1>Gender [Male].</COMMENTS1>
                <DESIGNATION>
                    <VALUE>Huthi military commander</VALUE>
                </DESIGNATION>
                <NATIONALITY>
                    <VALUE>Yemen</VALUE>
                </NATIONALITY>
                <LIST_TYPE>
                    <VALUE>UN List</VALUE>
                </LIST_TYPE>
                <LAST_DAY_UPDATED>
                    <VALUE>2014-11-20</VALUE>
                    <VALUE>2016-08-26</VALUE>
                </LAST_DAY_UPDATED>
                <INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS>
                    <QUALITY>Good</QUALITY>
                    <ALIAS_NAME>Abd-al-Khaliq al-Huthi</ALIAS_NAME>
                </INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS>
                <INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS>
                    <QUALITY>Good</QUALITY>
                    <ALIAS_NAME>Abd-al-Khaliq Badr-al-Din al Huthi</ALIAS_NAME>
                </INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS>
                <INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS>
                    <QUALITY>Good</QUALITY>
                    <ALIAS_NAME>‘Abd al-Khaliq Badr al-Din al-Huthi</ALIAS_NAME>
                </INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS>
                <INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS>
                    <QUALITY>Good</QUALITY>
                    <ALIAS_NAME>Abd al-Khaliq al-Huthi </ALIAS_NAME>
                </INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS>
                <INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS>
                    <QUALITY>Low</QUALITY>
                    <ALIAS_NAME>Abu-Yunus</ALIAS_NAME>
                </INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS>
                <INDIVIDUAL_ADDRESS>
                    <COUNTRY/>
                </INDIVIDUAL_ADDRESS>
                <INDIVIDUAL_DATE_OF_BIRTH>
                    <TYPE_OF_DATE>EXACT</TYPE_OF_DATE>
                    <YEAR>1984</YEAR>
                </INDIVIDUAL_DATE_OF_BIRTH>
                <INDIVIDUAL_PLACE_OF_BIRTH/>
                <INDIVIDUAL_DOCUMENT/>
                <SORT_KEY/>
                <SORT_KEY_LAST_MOD/>
            </INDIVIDUAL>

    </CONSOLIDATED_LIST>
```

The desired output is the following:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DATAID | FIRST_NAME | SECOND_NAME | THIRD_NAME | FOURTH_NAME | ALIAS_NAME | QUALITY
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
6908434 | ABD | AL-KHALIQ | AL-HOUTHI | NA | Abd-al-Khaliq al-Huthi | Good
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
6908434 | ABD | AL-KHALIQ | AL-HOUTHI | NA | Abd-al-Khaliq Badr-al-Din al Huthi | Good
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
6908434 | ABD | AL-KHALIQ | AL-HOUTHI | NA | ‘Abd al-Khaliq Badr al-Din al-Huthi | Good
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
6908434 | ABD | AL-KHALIQ | AL-HOUTHI | NA | Abd al-Khaliq al-Huthi | Good
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
6908434 | ABD | AL-KHALIQ | AL-HOUTHI | NA | Abu-Yunus | Low
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

One issue is that some entries do not have THIRD_NAME, and FOURTH_NAME. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Have tried using the following code:

```
result <- do.call(rbind,lapply(individuals,function(individual){
  DATAID      <- xmlValue(individual["DATAID"][[1]])
  FIRST_NAME  <- xmlValue(individual["FIRST_NAME"][[1]])
  SECOND_NAME <- xmlValue(individual["SECOND_NAME"][[1]])
  THIRD_NAME  <- xmlValue(individual["THIRD_NAME"][[1]])
  FOURTH_NAME <- xmlValue(individual["FOURTH_NAME"][[1]])
  c(DATAID = DATAID, FIRST_NAME = FIRST_NAME)
}))
result <- data.frame(result)
```

But failed with either there is no third_name, fourth_name, and also not sure of how to get the alias_names.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the following code is working:

```
un_xml <- xmlParse("~/Downloads/consolidated.xml")
entries <- length(xpathSApply(un_xml, "//INDIVIDUAL"))

getNameValue <- function(i_or_e,Node,i) {
    if (length(sapply(un_xml[paste0("//",i_or_e,"[",i,"]/",Node)], xmlName)) > 0) {
        NAME = sapply(un_xml[paste0("//",i_or_e,"[",i,"]/",Node)], xmlValue)
    } else {
        NAME = ''
    }
    NAME
}

getAliasValue <- function(i_or_e,Node,i) {
    if (length(sapply(un_xml[paste0("//",i_or_e,"[",i,"]/*/",Node)], xmlName)) > 0) {
        NAME = sapply(un_xml[paste0("//",i_or_e,"[",i,"]/*/",Node)], xmlValue)
    } else {
        NAME = ''
    }
    NAME
}

getUNListType <- function(i_or_e,i) {
    if (length(sapply(un_xml[paste0("//",i_or_e,"[",i,"]/UN_LIST_TYPE")], xmlName)) > 0) {
        NAME = sapply(un_xml[paste0("//",i_or_e,"[",i,"]/UN_LIST_TYPE")], xmlValue)
    } else {
        NAME = ''
    }
    NAME
}

getListType <- function(i_or_e,i) {
    if (length(sapply(un_xml[paste0("//",i_or_e,"[",i,"]/LIST_TYPE/VALUE")], xmlName)) > 0) {
        NAME = sapply(un_xml[paste0("//",i_or_e,"[",i,"]/LIST_TYPE/VALUE")], xmlValue)
    } else {
        NAME = ''
    }
    NAME
}


individuals <- lapply(seq(entries), function(i){
    data.frame(
        ID          = sapply(un_xml[paste0("//INDIVIDUAL[",i,"]/DATAID")], xmlValue),
        FIRST_NAME  = sapply(un_xml[paste0("//INDIVIDUAL[",i,"]/FIRST_NAME")], xmlValue),
        SECOND_NAME = getNameValue("INDIVIDUAL", "SECOND_NAME", i),
        THIRD_NAME  = getNameValue("INDIVIDUAL", "THIRD_NAME", i),
        FOURTH_NAME = getNameValue("INDIVIDUAL", "FOURTH_NAME", i),
        ALIAS_NAME  = getAliasValue("INDIVIDUAL", "ALIAS_NAME", i),
        QUALITY     = getAliasValue("INDIVIDUAL", "QUALITY", i),
        UN_LIST_TYPE = getUNListType("INDIVIDUAL", i),
        LIST_TYPE = getListType("INDIVIDUAL", i)
    )
})

individuals_df <- do.call(rbind, individuals)

entries <- length(xpathSApply(un_xml, "//ENTITY"))
entities <- lapply(seq(entries), function(i){
    data.frame(
        ID           = sapply(un_xml[paste0("//ENTITY[",i,"]/DATAID")], xmlValue),
        FIRST_NAME   = getNameValue("ENTITY", "FIRST_NAME", i),
        SECOND_NAME  = getNameValue("ENTITY", "SECOND_NAME", i),
        THIRD_NAME   = getNameValue("ENTITY", "THIRD_NAME", i),
        FOURTH_NAME  = getNameValue("ENTITY", "FOURTH_NAME", i),
        ALIAS_NAME   = getAliasValue("ENTITY", "ALIAS_NAME", i),
        QUALITY      = getAliasValue("ENTITY", "QUALITY", i),
        UN_LIST_TYPE = getUNListType("ENTITY", i),
        LIST_TYPE    = getListType("ENTITY", i)        
    )
})

entities_df <- do.call(rbind, entities)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider transforming your original XML with [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files into other XML, HTML, even text (i.e., csv, tab) files. Specifically, for your needs of a long format, locate the `<INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS>` and migrate over the indicators in above ancestor `<INDIVIDUAL>` node. Once transformed, you can easily import with XML's `xpathSApply()` calls or `xmlToDataFrame()`. Another worthwhile reason to go with XSLT is you can create empty nodes that may or may not be filled such as the optional `<THIRD_NAME>` or `<FOURTH_NAME>` elements.

The only challenge is R does not have a universal package for XSLT transformation across operating systems. However, R can call such XSLT processors available at command line with `system()`. Most OS carry xslt processors and general-purpose languages (C#, Java, Python, Perl, VB) maintain such libraries. On most Linux/Mac distributions, [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html) is available. For Windows, you can run a COM call to [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759204(v=vs.85).aspx). Of course you can use any other third-party processor such as [Saxon, Xalan, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info).

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file --fully compliant xml file-- to be called at command line)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/CONSOLIDATED_LIST">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="INDIVIDUALS"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="INDIVIDUALS">    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="INDIVIDUAL"/>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="INDIVIDUAL">    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS"/>    
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS">
    <INDIVIDUAL>
      <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::INDIVIDUAL/DATAID"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::INDIVIDUAL/FIRST_NAME"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::INDIVIDUAL/SECOND_NAME"/>
      <THIRD_NAME><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::INDIVIDUAL/THIRD_NAME"/></THIRD_NAME>
      <FOURTH_NAME><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::INDIVIDUAL/FOURTH_NAME"/></FOURTH_NAME>
      <ALIAS><xsl:value-of select="ALIAS_NAME"/></ALIAS>
      <QUALITY><xsl:value-of select="QUALITY"/></QUALITY>
    </INDIVIDUAL>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**R** *(for Linux/Mac using command line xsltproc)*

```
system("xsltproc /path/to/xslt_script.xsl path/to/input.xml -o /path/to/output.xml")
```

**R** *(for Windows using MSXML COM object)*

```
library(RDCOMClient)

xmlfile <- "C:/path/to/Input.xml"
xslfile <- "C:/path/to/XSLT_Script.xsl"
output <- "C:/path/to/Output.xml"

xmlDoc <- COMCreate("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xslDoc <- COMCreate("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
newDoc <- COMCreate("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

xmlDoc$Load(xmlfile)
xslDoc$Load(xslfile)

xmlDoc$transformNodeToObject(xslDoc, newDoc)
newDoc$Save(output)

xmlDoc <- NULL; xslDoc <- NULL; newDoc <- NULL
```

**R** *(after above transformation, two approaches)*

```
library(XML)

doc <- xmlParse("/path/to/output.xml")

# XPATHSAPPLY APPROACH -------------------------
df <-  data.frame( 
    DATAID = xpathSApply(doc, "//DATAID", xmlValue),
    FIRST_NAME  = xpathSApply(doc, "//FIRST_NAME", xmlValue),
    SECOND_NAME = xpathSApply(doc, "//SECOND_NAME", xmlValue),
    THIRD_NAME  = xpathSApply(doc, "//THIRD_NAME", xmlValue),
    FOURTH_NAME = xpathSApply(doc, "//FOURTH_NAME", xmlValue),
    ALIAS = xpathSApply(doc, "//ALIAS", xmlValue),
    QUALITY = xpathSApply(doc, "//QUALITY", xmlValue),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
# REPLACE EMPTY STRING WITH NAs
df <- data.frame(sapply(df, function(col) ifelse(col=="", NA, col)))

# XMLTODATAFRAME APPROACH -------------------------
df2 <- xmlToDataFrame(doc, nodes=getNodeSet(doc, "//INDIVIDUAL"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# REPLACE EMPTY STRING WITH NAs
df2 <- data.frame(sapply(df2, function(col) ifelse(col=="", NA, col)))

all.equal(df, df2)
# [1] TRUE

df2
#    DATAID FIRST_NAME SECOND_NAME  THIRD_NAME FOURTH_NAME                              ALIAS QUALITY
# 1 6908434        ABD   AL-KHALIQ  AL-HOUTHI         <NA>             Abd-al-Khaliq al-Huthi    Good
# 2 6908434        ABD   AL-KHALIQ  AL-HOUTHI         <NA> Abd-al-Khaliq Badr-al-Din al Huthi    Good
# 3 6908434        ABD   AL-KHALIQ  AL-HOUTHI         <NA> Abd al-Khaliq Badr al-Din al-Huthi    Good
# 4 6908434        ABD   AL-KHALIQ  AL-HOUTHI         <NA>             Abd al-Khaliq al-Huthi    Good
# 5 6908434        ABD   AL-KHALIQ  AL-HOUTHI         <NA>                          Abu-Yunus     Low
```

Comment: Thanks Parfait, it is great help.